# Dynamic index type in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I'm working on a solution where I need to ingest data to ElasticSearch where the index type can vary. Is there any dynamic template in Elastic that can take care of the dynamic index type.

Comment: can you provide an example of your use case